# How to use Alfresco rest api to create folder in a site/documentLibrary?

Tags: rest, postman, alfresco

I have installed Alfresco and I would like to create folder in a specific site and under specific document library.

There is link [hear](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/references/RESTful-NodeFolderPost.html) saying the query should look like this:

```
POST /alfresco/service/api/node/folder/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}
POST /alfresco/service/api/site/folder/{site}/{container}/{path}
POST /alfresco/service/api/site/folder/{site}/{container}
```

but if I try it in the postman I get the below error:

```
hxxp://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/service/api/site/folder/mikesite/documentLibrary/hello
```

[image]

[image]

And here is the response:

```
{
    "status": {
        "code": 404,
        "name": "Not Found",
        "description": "Requested resource is not available."
    },
    "message": "",
    "exception": "",
    "callstack": [],
    "server": "Community v5.2.0 (re21f2be5-b22) schema 10,057",
    "time": "May 29, 2018 1:10:51 AM"
}
```

Please let me know how I could do this.

Many thanks for any clue.

Comment: As @vikash says, your "hello" path must exist in the document library. I've confirmed that it works. As you are using 5.2 you might want to consider using the 5.2 REST API instead of the old web script based API, see https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/nodes/createNode

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the exact path of your site folder which has to be available in site.

So for your example hello folder has to be available in your site document library.